# counting elements in bash array that don't begin with a specific character

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that counts all elements in an array that don't begin with the character '-' (it's part of a shell-completion script that counts the arguments and not the options in the `words` array).
A Python equivalent to what I'm trying to write would be:

```
len([word for word in words if not word.startswith("-")])
```

I wrote some code that works fine but since I'm very new to bash scripting, I'm sure that some improvements can be made, and I'm wondering if I missed some better way to implement this that doesn't involve so many lines of code, maybe something that looks more like the Python implementation?

This is what I have:

```
words=('a' 'b' '-c' 'd' '--foo' 'e')
argcount=0
for word in ${words[@]}
do
    if [[ $word =~ ^[^-].*$ ]] ; then
        ((argcount++))
    fi
done
echo $argcount
```

Any improvement is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
for word in "${words[@]}"
```

which should work even if some argument contain whitespace. Also, instead of a regular expression, you can use a normal pattern matching:

```
if [[ $word != -* ]] ; then
```

Other than that, I do not see anything. Bash is not as concise as Python or Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep` to count the lines for you:

```
$ words=('a' 'b' '-c' 'd' '--foo' 'e')
$ argcount=$( printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}" | grep -vc "^-" )
```

(Assuming no word in `words` can contain an embedded newline, which seems like a safe enough assumption.)

If you must use pure `bash`, and don't want to use patterns as choroba suggests, you can negate the result of the regular expression match:

```
if ! [[ $word =~ ^- ]]; then
    (( argcount++ ))
fi
```